# Create cumulative time data for a group

Tags: r, date, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe with ID's, event dates, dates.

```
timeyrs = endate - startdate

eventyr = eventdate - startdate
```

NB: I have rounded these numbers.

`df1`

```
ID  eventdate   startdate   enddate     timeyrs eventyr
1   20-10-2007  16-06-2003  21-07-2017  14.1  4.34
1   11-11-08    16-06-2003  21-07-2017  14.1  5.41
1   26-09-2012  16-06-2003  21-07-2017  14.1  9.28
2   11-05-2014  20-04-2012  16-06-2017  5.2   2.06
3   11-04-2017  6-02-2015   21-04-2017  2.2   2.18
```

I would like to summarise the data for the whole dataset into years of follow up data. ie, 1 row for each year (approx 20 years).

`df2` to create:

```
Year cmltime cmlevent
1   3   0
2   3   0
3   2.2 2
4   2   0
5   2   1
6   1.2 1
7   1   0
8   1   0
9   1   0
10  1   1
11  1   0
12  1   0
13  1   0
14  1   0
15  0.1 0
```

For cumulative time - this is the amount of data available for that year eg. for the first year, there are 3 ID's that contribute a full year worth of data and finally only 1 year of dat for years 6-14.

For cumulative event, this is the sum of the vents that occur in that follow up year. eg. ID"s 2 and 3 had events in the 3rd year of their data.

I have been trialling code from dplyr for this with no luck so far. Suggestions welcome!

Comment: What is `time.sum` the sum of from your original data?

Comment: Hi @Relasta, I have updated my questions with a better example

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to create for each `ID` an own time scale where year one starts at `startdate` individually. Finally, the results are aggregated across years.

Below is a code which combines `data.table` syntax for grouping and aggregating and `magrittr` pipes for the arithmetic. (BTW, it was a good exercise to exploit the wealth of `magrittr`'s piping functions.)

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
cml_by_ID <- DT[, {
  cmltime <- seq(min(startdate), max(enddate), by = "year") %>% 
    append(max(enddate)) %>% 
    diff() %>% 
    as.numeric() %>% 
    divide_by(365.25) %>% 
    round(1)
  year <- cmltime %>% seq_along()
  cmlevent <- year %>% 
    is_in(
      eventdate %>% 
        subtract(min(startdate)) %>% 
        as.numeric() %>% 
        divide_by(365.25) %>% 
        ceiling()
    ) %>% 
    as.integer()
  list(year = year, cmltime = cmltime, cmlevent = cmlevent)
  }, 
  by = ID]
```

The core idea is to create a sequence of yearly dates beginning with `startdate`, appending `enddate` and computing the differences measured in years. So, `cmltime` contains the shares of the yearly contributions of observation time (mostly 1.0 except for the last year). `year` is simply counted along `cmltime`. Finally, the years in which events took place are determined. `cmlevent` is set to one for those years.

The result for each `ID` is combined in one data object

```
cml_by_ID
```

> ```
>     ID year cmltime cmlevent
>  1:  1    1     1.0        0
>  2:  1    2     1.0        0
>  3:  1    3     1.0        0
>  4:  1    4     1.0        0
>  5:  1    5     1.0        1
>  6:  1    6     1.0        1
>  7:  1    7     1.0        0
>  8:  1    8     1.0        0
>  9:  1    9     1.0        0
> 10:  1   10     1.0        1
> 11:  1   11     1.0        0
> 12:  1   12     1.0        0
> 13:  1   13     1.0        0
> 14:  1   14     1.0        0
> 15:  1   15     0.1        0
> 16:  2    1     1.0        0
> 17:  2    2     1.0        0
> 18:  2    3     1.0        1
> 19:  2    4     1.0        0
> 20:  2    5     1.0        0
> 21:  2    6     0.2        0
> 22:  3    1     1.0        0
> 23:  3    2     1.0        0
> 24:  3    3     0.2        1
>     ID year cmltime cmlevent
> ```

Finally, this is aggregated for each year:

```
cml_by_ID[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = c("cmltime", "cmlevent"), by = year]
```

> ```
>     year cmltime cmlevent
>  1:    1     3.0        0
>  2:    2     3.0        0
>  3:    3     2.2        2
>  4:    4     2.0        0
>  5:    5     2.0        1
>  6:    6     1.2        1
>  7:    7     1.0        0
>  8:    8     1.0        0
>  9:    9     1.0        0
> 10:   10     1.0        1
> 11:   11     1.0        0
> 12:   12     1.0        0
> 13:   13     1.0        0
> 14:   14     1.0        0
> 15:   15     0.1        0
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
  "ID  eventdate   startdate   enddate     timeyrs eventyr
1   20-10-2007  16-06-2003  21-07-2017  14.1  4.34
1   11-11-08    16-06-2003  21-07-2017  14.1  5.41
1   26-09-2012  16-06-2003  21-07-2017  14.1  9.28
2   11-05-2014  20-04-2012  16-06-2017  5.2   2.06
3   11-04-2017  6-02-2015   21-04-2017  2.2   2.18",
  select = 1:4
)
# convert date strings to Date class
cols <- names(DT)[names(DT) %like% "date$"]
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, lubridate::dmy), .SDcols = cols]
DT
```

> ```
>    ID  eventdate  startdate    enddate
> 1:  1 2007-10-20 2003-06-16 2017-07-21
> 2:  1 2008-11-11 2003-06-16 2017-07-21
> 3:  1 2012-09-26 2003-06-16 2017-07-21
> 4:  2 2014-05-11 2012-04-20 2017-06-16
> 5:  3 2017-04-11 2015-02-06 2017-04-21
> ```